# Lipschitz not contraction with a unique fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

Define the scalar function $ g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$  g(x):= \dfrac{x^2}{1+|x| +x^{2}}.  $$
It is clear that $g$ is Lipschitzian and has a unique fixed point $x=0$ (one can prove that easily by assuming the converse).
My question is to prove that $g$ is not a strict contraction. There is any hint or any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Based on its graph, I'd go for a proof by contradiction. Suppose there exists $\alpha\in\left]0,1\right[$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq\alpha|x-y|$ and arrive at a contradiction. Notice that $g$ approaches horizontal asymptotes as $x\to\pm\infty$, so that's probably where you'll break the inequality.

Comment: @KamalKhalil Are you sure it's not a strict contraction?

Comment: Show $|g(x)-g(0)|/|x-0| \to 1$ at $\infty.$

Comment: @zhw $|g(x)-g(0)|/|x| = |x|/(1+|x|+x^2 ) \rightarrow 0 $ at $\infty$ (not to $1$)!

Comment: @PierreCarre I believe that it is not a contraction (even if it has a unique fixed point). However, can you 'hint' how it is a contraction ?

Comment: @Zim Thank you for your hint, but $|g(x)|/|x|$ goes to $0$ at $\pm \infty $?

Comment: @KamalKhalil Whoops you're right, thank you.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure if I understood your vocabulary. By "strict" do you mean $(\forall x\neq y\in\mathbb{R})\quad |g(x)-g(y)|<|x-y|$ or did you mean $(\exists \alpha \in \left]0,1\right[)$ such that $(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R})\quad |g(x)-g(y)|\leq \alpha |x-y|$? Because it appears it does satisfy the first notion (as @PierreCarre mentioned) but might not satisfy the second.

Comment: @KamalKhalil Since $g$ is nonlinear, my impression is that checking $|g(x)|/|x|$ doesn't really give us a good intuition on whether or not it is a contraction. We have to use the notion of contraction that has differences. zhw's approach would have been sufficient to show it is not a contraction, but since the limit goes to $0$ and not $1$ it's inconclusive

Comment: @Zim I mean by strict contraction the definition you gived in your first comment i.e.  |()−()|≤|−|  with $0< \alpha <1$. I wanted to examine the term |()|/||  to find a contradiction because of $g(0)=0$ not to prove that it is a strict contraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |g'(x)|$ is a Lipschitz constant for $g$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties),then [this graph looks like](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/klbn0uxwt5) $g$ is a strict contraction with $\alpha\approx0.532$.

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable remark. I tried to calculate the derivative using Mathematica but it gives an error with the absolue value. Afterward I tried  the function $ g(x)=x^2 /(1+x+x^2) $ (without the absolue value) which is different with $\sup |g'(x)| \geq 1$. However, I don't know how "desmos" calculator works with the derivative of the absolute value. Many kind regards

Comment: @KamalKhalil yeah in general the absolute value is not differentiable at $0$, which is probably why Mathematica is complaining. Since $g$ is smooth everywhere else (on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$), $g'$ is well-defined and we can see its boundedness. So, to settle the question about the derivative at $0$, if you look at the left-hand and right-hand limit of the derivative, they will be equal. We can even see visually that the tangent of $g$ has slope $0$ at $0$.

Comment: Zim Okay! this is clear to me. Thank you very much again! Now, I am working with 'Desmos' to find a good example. My best wishes.